# admob did I implemented my code correctly?

Tags: android, admob

Currently I make money with my apps. Not I made another one and added an AdView. The problem is, that the dot in admob UI is still red. My code is

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
               android:id="@+id/ad"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
               ads:adSize="BANNER"
               ads:adUnitId="_______"
               ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
               ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" >
           </com.google.ads.AdView>
```

**I'm getting ads on my phone**, but admob won't acknowledge it

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an ads:adUnitId field.  So it doesn't know who you are.

Comment: I think he has replaced it with '_______' to prevent others from using the id.

Comment: Ah, my eyes skipped over it.  Sorry.